# How to distinguish read / write operation in boost serialization?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Using the boost serialization library I have a very simple `serialize()` member function, something like:

```
template <class Archive>
  void serialize( Archive& ar, unsigned version )
  {
     ar & m_Searcher;
  }
```

... and I want to keep it this simple (I don't want to use splitting in particular). But in the case of writing I want to do some "preparation" for `m_Searcher` before actual writing to take place.

```
{
  if( this-is-a-writing-operation )
     do-some-preparation( m_Searcher )

  ar & m_Searcher;
}
```

Is there any simple way to distinguish between reading and writing operations?

Comment: if you don't mind splitting the logic in two functions, take a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#splitting

Answer (score 27):

I think you can do this without splitting, which would be the usual way:

```
if (Archive::is_saving::value) 
   doSomething();
```

This is inherited from the base interface that the Archives use, in `boost/archive/detail/interface_[ia]archive.hpp`

The following code demonstrates that it seems to be a reasonable solution with 1.42

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>

// oarchive:
//text
static_assert(!boost::archive::text_oarchive::is_loading::value, "out is loading");
static_assert(boost::archive::text_oarchive::is_saving::value, "out isn't saving");

//xml
static_assert(!boost::archive::xml_oarchive::is_loading::value, "out is loading");
static_assert(boost::archive::xml_oarchive::is_saving::value, "out isn't saving");

// iarchive:
//text
static_assert(boost::archive::text_iarchive::is_loading::value, "out is loading");
static_assert(!boost::archive::text_iarchive::is_saving::value, "out isn't saving");

//xml
static_assert(boost::archive::xml_iarchive::is_loading::value, "out is loading");
static_assert(!boost::archive::xml_iarchive::is_saving::value, "out isn't saving");
```

I'd be a bit cautious of relying on something like this though -- multiple inheritance might break it if someone wrote an archive that does both input and output *and* it's not clear to me how permenant and public this part of the interface is meant to be.

Comment: As some kind of protection check against the aforementioned issue with the possible bi-directional archive one may add `static_assert(Archive::is_saving::value != Archive::is_loading::value);`